# Line Separator of Flex Tile List

Tags: apache-flex, list, drag-and-drop, flex4

I am creating one application in Adobe AIR with Flex 4.6.
In that, I had created one List with TileLayout.
And also I want to do drag & drop in that list only.
So I had enabled drag & drop option in that list.

But the problem is when I do drag & drop, line separator(or position indicator - *I don't know what it exactly called*) for placing(or dropping) one component at any particular position is not proper visible.
I want to customize that line separator in my way.

So how can I skin(or customize) that line separator??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Spark list, check the  `dropIndicator` skin part (or `dropIndicatorSkin` style): [live docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#SkinPartSummary).

Hope this helps.